# ACA Individual Mandate effect on Taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, affordable-care-act

This seems to be a sticky situation for the beginning of the year, and although it is a pressure point for President Trump, it seems to me that it causes undue complications during the height of the tax season.

For instance, the IRS requires all previous year taxes to be filed by April 15th, but taxes can be filed as soon as the W-2 (or equivalent) is given. Due to the individual mandate, taxes are being taken as a penalty.

If the ACA individual mandate is repealed, how will that affect someone who has already filed (and paid) on their taxes?

Comment: You can get apply for tax returns for several years I understand. And do you expect them to make a repeal retroactive?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt I don't expect anything, I'm curious as to the budget repercussions of repeal. Less tax income means projections will need to be revised, and that may affect other legislation as well.

Comment: You're filing *last year's* taxes. Anything happening this year won't be applicable.

Comment: The comment reads like you care about effect on the government, but the question seems centered on the effect on people.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt To an extent, it's both. Taxes are levied from the people and given to the government. It's not so much a question on "effect on people" vs "effect on government", rather its a question on "the effect reduced taxes have".

Comment: I was suggesting that you might want to be clear exactly what you are asking. "where does my ACA tax go if there is no longer ACA?" Is a fine question about how taxes work. "What does repealing (part of) ACA do to the budget?" Is fine question about a budget item. "What happens when taxes are reduced?" might be too broad, but certainly resources could be pointed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the IRS is requiring a PREVIOUS year's taxes to be filed by mid-April of the following year, then a repeal, which would be effective at a current or future date, should not affect the taxes for the previous tax year.